# Pandas filtering with np.where as filter not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

working on Kaggle's SpaceShip Titanic dataset and I was doing some analysis of the data.
Call `tt` the `pd.DataFrame` containing the data. I sum all the monetary variables and then try to filter by both having `TotalExp==0 and CryoSleep.isna()`, yet in the results I get both people with CryoSleep **not nan** and people with **TotalExp not 0**

```
monetary = ['RoomService', 'FoodCourt', 'ShoppingMall', 'Spa', 'VRDeck']
tt.loc[:,'TotalExp'] = tt.loc[:,monetary].sum(axis=1)
tt.loc[np.where((tt.TotalExp == 0.0) & (tt.CryoSleep.isna()))][['CryoSleep','TotalExp']]
```

Example of current output:

| index | CryoSleep | TotalExp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1405 | NaN | **977.0** |
| 1417 | **False** | 0.0 |
| 1454 | NaN | **3862.0** |
| 1531 | NaN | 0.0 |
| 1565 | NaN | **906.0** |

I have tried both filters separately and the behavior is the same in each case (bringing cases that should not).

The expected behavior is that only rows where CryoSleep is NaN and TotalExp = 0, both at the same time, are displayed.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the code to select the rows where `CryoSleep` is `NaN` and `TotalExp` is `0`, you can modify the last line of the code as follows:
I work on sample `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a sample dataframe
tt = pd.DataFrame({
    'RoomService': [10, 0, 20, 0, 30],
    'FoodCourt': [20, 0, 30, 0, 40],
    'ShoppingMall': [30, 0, 40, 0, 50],
    'Spa': [40, 0, 50, 0, 60],
    'VRDeck': [50, 0, 60, 0, 70],
    'CryoSleep': [np.NaN, 1, 0, 1, np.NaN]
})

# sum the monetary columns and assign to TotalExp column
monetary = ['RoomService', 'FoodCourt', 'ShoppingMall', 'Spa', 'VRDeck']
tt.loc[:, 'TotalExp'] = tt.loc[:, monetary].sum(axis=1)

# select the rows where CryoSleep is NaN and TotalExp is 0
selected_data = tt.loc[(tt['CryoSleep'].isna()) & (tt['TotalExp'] == 0), ['CryoSleep', 'TotalExp']]

# print the selected data
print(selected_data)
```

You don't need `np.where` to get the result but if you still want to use that function try following code;

````
selected_data = tt.loc[np.where((tt['CryoSleep'].isna()) & (tt['TotalExp'] == 0)), ['CryoSleep', 'TotalExp']]
```
````